# How do I expose css files installed from npm?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass

I'm creating a Sass/css library, and I'm hosting it on npm. I'd like to know if there's a good way to expose it to the client, so they could do this:

`@import 'library_name'`

Rather than something ugly like this

`@import 'node-modules/library_name/library_name'`

I realize npm is originally made for javascript modules, but it's evolved quite a bit from that, yet I can't seem to find a good way to host only css.

Comment: You may ask developers install and use https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-css

Comment: And I'm wondering is it for node server or gulp/grunt tool?

Comment: Also Using NPM on The Client Side http://dontkry.com/posts/code/using-npm-on-the-client-side.html (scroll to STYLESHEETS). And as you can see there is no way to load css from npm module out of the folder `node-modules/`

Comment: Its for front end. I only wanted to serve it through npm because of its popularity and the versioning.

Comment: Is your module installed on the server or on client-side? I understand it is for front-end :) CSS is only for front-end

Comment: Haha yea poor choice of words. I literally want people to get  two scss files when they install it and if possible a simple import path. So client side.

Comment: Why not bower then? http://bower.io/. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-front-end-javascript-and-css-dependencies-with-bower-on-ubuntu-14-04 Scroll to Step 5

Comment: Well it hardly solves the problem. Its just that Id be targetting 'bower-components' instead of 'node_modules'

Comment: So the answer is -- import your css directly like `/node_modules/lin_name/main.css`

Answer (score 0):

I would symlink them into a folder called 'third-party' and check in the symlinks, which would allow me to `@import 'third-party/library-name'`.  You could also symlink them to your styles directory, but when you get a file not found error, the third-party prefix would make it easier for other developers to realize they need to `npm i`, rather than `git pull`.